# Laravel Nova - Scope Relationship Fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-nova

Is there a way of adding a scope to the BelongsToMany fields, such that when you attach related models you can only do so from restricted options?

Example:

**Post** belongsToMany **Tags** (using Spatie/Laravel-Tags).
**Tags** belongsToMany **Posts**.

Tags model has **id**, **name**, **slug**, **type** and **timestamp** properties.

On the Detail or Update views, I would like to be able to attach Tags to Post.

Using the default BelongsToMany field (or a third-party package) on the Post resource allows for me to add Tags to Post.

*App\Nova\Post.php*

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
            BelongsToMany::make('Tags'),
}
```

However, I would like to only be able to add Tags **where type = 'Books'** to this model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Spatie Tags package, I'd suggest using their [Nova Tags package](https://github.com/spatie/nova-tags-field). Then you can add the following to your field definitions:

```
Tags::make('Tags')->type('books'),
```

This will limit the available tags for that resource to those of type *books*. See the entry on the [Nova Tags package](https://github.com/spatie/nova-tags-field#using-types) and the base [Spatie Tags package](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-tags/v2/advanced-usage/using-types/)